# Control what is being display on remote browser with a button?

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, joomla, server

I been developing a Digital Signage system using lighttpd web server and Joomla for almost 2 years now and I been adding extra features, now I would like to add remote interaction from another browser and I was wondering if there is a way to change the current URL from the local display from a remote browser by pressing a button?

Comment: I cannot make sense of your question. Perhaps you mean 'tablet' instead of 'table'? But even then...

Comment: Digital Signage base on a web server running on a TV  change the current URL from a remote browser. Do you understand now?

Comment: WebSockets is the answer

Comment: Ah, yes, I get it, sorry for that. A `Digital Signage` like this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signage and you want to control the content that is show from a browser on another device. Yes, of course that is possible, what is exactly the problem you have?

Comment: Yes, instead of polling you could use websockets: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics Remember this keeps a connection open, you cannot use it if you have hundreds of displays.

Comment: Dude no problem I'm the one in need of help i was just trying to be as clear as possible. Thanks let me take a look.